'publishToMavenLocal' does not work when the dependency block is empty
I get this error if my module's dependency block is empty:
Execution failed for task ':model:generateMetadataFileForModelPublication'.
> Invalid publication 'model':
    - Publication only contains dependencies and/or constraints without a version. You should add minimal version information, publish resolved versions

I need to create a module that will have common classes. To do this, I only need the lombok dependency. It is added via the main build.gradle of the project
main build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
}

group = 'com.mygroup'
version = '0.0.1'
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

bootJar {
    enabled = false
}
subprojects {

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

    java {
        sourceCompatibility = '17'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://artifactory.mycom.com/artifactory/cms"
            credentials {
                username = getConfigurationProperty('ARTIFACTORY_USER', 'artifactory_user')
                password = getConfigurationProperty('ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD', 'artifactory_password')
            }
        }
    }


    configurations {
        compileOnly {
            extendsFrom annotationProcessor
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure'

        annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
        compileOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
        compileOnly 'com.playtika.reactivefeign:feign-reactor-spring-configuration:3.2.1'

        compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
        annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

        testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

String getConfigurationProperty(String envVar, String sysProp) {
    System.getenv(envVar) ?: project.findProperty(sysProp)
}

module build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

group = 'com.mygroup.extension'
version = '0.0.1'

bootJar {
    enabled = false
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}

dependencies {
}

ext {
    set('version_suffix', "${'master'.equalsIgnoreCase(getCurrentGitBranch()) || 'HEAD'.equalsIgnoreCase(getCurrentGitBranch()) ? '' : '.1.' + getCurrentGitBranch().toString().replace('/', '-')}")
}

publishing {
    publications {
        model(MavenPublication) {
            version = project.version + project.version_suffix
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = 'https://artifactory.mycom.com/artifactory/cms'
            credentials {
                username = getConfigurationProperty('ARTIFACTORY_USER', 'artifactory_user')
                password = getConfigurationProperty('ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD', 'artifactory_password')
            }
        }
    }
}

String getConfigurationProperty(String envVar, String sysProp) {
    System.getenv(envVar) ?: project.findProperty(sysProp)
}

publish.dependsOn build

compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

def getCurrentGitBranch() {
    def ciBranchName = System.getenv("CI_COMMIT_BRANCH")
    if (ciBranchName != null && ciBranchName != "")
        return ciBranchName
    def gitBranch = "master"
    try {
        def workingDir = new File("${project.projectDir}")
        def result = 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD'.execute(null, workingDir)
        result.waitFor()
        if (result.exitValue() == 0) {
            gitBranch = result.text.trim()
        }
    } catch (e) {
    }
    return gitBranch
}

When adding any version dependency, the problem disappears. Gradle version 8.10.2
